# Register WireMock Extension with Port from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, port, junit5, wiremock

I'm trying to register a WireMockExtension with the port number from application.properties. How do I do that?

I have tried this code, but it produces a random port.

`BaseIntegrationTest.java`

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class BaseIntegrationTest {
  ...
  @Value("${port}")
  private int port;

  @RegisterExtension
  protected WireMockExtension wm = WireMockExtension.newInstance().options(
      wireMockConfig().port(port).extensions(NoKeepAliveTransformer.class)).build();
  ...

  public void test1() {
    System.out.println(wm.getPort());  // some random number that change in every test
    System.out.println(port);          // 18090
  }
```

`applications.properties`

```
port=18090
```

**Edit:**
Random number got from `System.out.println(wm.getPort());` is caused because `wm` is initialized with `port = 0` (default value of integer). This happens because the `@RegisterExtension` run first before the `port` variable is assigned from `@Value("${port}")`.

Comment: `18090`: ! random port can be explained with: `port` being `==0` at the moment of `wieMockConfig` (in "class body"... "class body" always happens *before* constructor, "spring magic" only after that)

Comment: Tried with: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#features-wiremock !? ..this is also linked from official (wiremock) doc: https://wiremock.org/docs/spring-boot/

Comment: .."spring magic": can take place after or *in* (i.e. by "constructor injection") constructor of a "spring managed object"(which is prerequisite to use `@org.spring...Value`), but in "class body" all "spring managed things" are "uninitialized"..

Comment: @xerx593 Could you please explain more about the link you sent? I have read and don't get which part is correlated which this problem. Thank you. I'm still very new to this framework.

Comment: add `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner` test dependency, then in (src/test/...!) application.properties just `wiremock.server.port=18090` ...add `@AutoConfigureWireMock`, then happy stubbing/testing (with static methods)